# How to get latest added partition in Glue table?

Tags: boto3, amazon-athena

How to get latest added partition in Glue table?
There is a library from which I can filter the partition

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.26.99/reference/services/glue/client/list_crawls.html

But how to filter using END_DATE, type of END_DATE in return statement is datetime and in Filters it is asking only for string.